# Dismiss and Present A View On Button Click From Another View

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a container view that has a table view inside of it. When I select a cell on the table view it presents a view controller(1). This view controller has a button in it that presents another view controller(2). When I leave 2 I need 1 to reload it's data. I'm assuming to do this I need to dismiss and present 1 again after leaving 2. How can I accomplish this?

VC1 Code For Presenting VC2:

```
    @IBAction func contributeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if totalContributions >= NeedStore.shared.currentNeed!.amount {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "This need has already been fully contributed to.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Contribute", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContributeViewController") as! ContributeViewController
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

VC2 Code For Switching Back To VC1:

```
    func detailView() {
    ApiManager.shared.getNeed(needId: NeedStore.shared.currentNeed!.id) { (need) in
        NeedStore.shared.currentNeed = need
        ApiManager.shared.getNeedUser { (object) in
            if object {
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NeedDetail", bundle: Bundle.main)
                let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NeedDetailViewController") as! NeedDetailViewController
                viewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
                viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also handle this in `viewDidAppear` of view controller (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidAppear()` of your VC(1) add `self.tableview.reloadData()`

If that doesn't work, you might need to create a delegate, so it knows you are leaving VC(2), entering(1), and refresh it.

UPDATE -

Added delegate method

```
protocol: ViewController2Delegate: class {
 func reloadTableView()
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {


weak var delegate: ViewController2Delegate?

@IBOutlet func goBackButton () {
 delegate.reloadTableView()
 }
}
```

VC1 -

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController, ViewController2Delegate {
 func reloadTableView() {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
   *- Whatever code you might be using to call your data too-*
 }

}
```

Comment: I suppose I misspoke and that's my fault. There's the table view which would technically be the first view controller. Selecting a cell on it brings up what I called VC(1). A button off of that brings up another view and when I leave that final view I need the view that comes up after clicking on the cell to refresh it's data. We've tried reloading the tableView data and that hasn't worked yet.

Comment: So, TableView -> TableViewCell -> VC1(Refresh this?) -> VC2?

Comment: Table View -> Click TableView Cell -> VC1 comes up -> Click button VC1 -> VC2 comes up -> When VC2 dismisses VC1 needs to refresh it's data. I have it all the way running it's viewDidLoad again and the data still isn't refreshing.

Comment: try something simple, add in the viewDidLoad() of the VC1 print ("testing if this method is working")

If this prints, this means viewDidLoad() is being called when VC2 is being dismissed.

let me know :)

Comment: I actually already did that that's how I know viewDidLoad() is running again when I leave VC2. So, that's why I'm confused on why nothing is updating. All the information is retrieved from a Alamofire call to a database and I have that call made when I load VC1 and when I leave VC2 and there is still no update. We make the call and store the information locally.

Comment: I'm not talking about viewDidLoad() though, don't get your lifecycles mixed up.

next thing you can try - VC2 -> prepareForSegue ->VC1(didSet{ reload your data }

Comment: Start showing some code so I know how to help, I'm giving really general answers here.

Comment: I'll update the question with code. I only said viewDidLoad() because in the previous comment you suggested I put a print statement there. One moment and I'll have the question updated.

Comment: Ah derp, I'm getting confused with all the messages we keep exchanging too, haha...my bad

Comment: That doesn't have the viewDidAppear() or viewDidLoad() on VC1 because it's a lot of code, but that's how I'm currently switching between them. A hard segue doesn't work because everything has to stay presented over the table view. Which is why I'm having issues. If I was just segueing back and forth I'd be okay.

Comment: Have you worked with delegation before? That's the best case scenario right now, I posted some off the mind code I'm nowhere near a PC right now.

Basically declare a protocol in VC2 and when button is clicked pass the delegate, in VC1 listen to the delegate and reloadData()

Comment: The views have all of there content inside a UIView and the area around it is clear. They kind of function as custom alert boxes. Is the best way to think of them.

Comment: I'll research that and see if I can't get it to work! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @RileyOsborne NP.